# How are microservices routed when tested locally

Tags: routes, microservices

When we talk of microservices based systems, routing is an important aspect as requests are to be directed to correct service. And components like load balancer, API gateways etc are used for the purpose when services are deployed in production.

But when I am developing and Howtesting microservices locally, say using Spring boot, I don't use any such component like loadbalancer, API gateway etc. So what takes care of routing?

Answer (score 0):

Well the concept remains same for local or remote. In either of the environments you have to tell service a to communicate to service b. That action is established via service discovery. You become the client and register yourself to the service discovery like other application services and invoke a call via Feign or Ribbon what ever you chose.
In local you can also hardcode the host and port via Feign for the service which want to communicate but thats not ideal way for the service to communicate.

For local You can also use ResponseEntity to communicate between the service for example :-

```
ResponseEntity<ServiceA> responseEntity = new RestTemplate().getForEntity
        ("http://localhost:8000/ServiceB/from/{from}/to/{to}",ServiceB.class, parametervalues);
```